# How to get data from a parameterized constructor?

Tags: java

So i have String[] data that is returned from the parameterized constructor stringTokenizer(String str)

The question is how do you write the code in the method below so that the variable "tokens" can get the data from the constructor above

```
public String[] arr(String str){
    String[] tokens = null;
    tokens = str.split("\\s+");      
    return tokens;
}
public void print(){
    String[] tokens = arr(); //How am i suppose to write this line so that i an get the data from the method above?
    int size = tokens.length;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        System.out.print(tokens[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not a constructor. Post a full example. This question makes little sense.

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). It'll help you understand better.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor would store the initialized tokens in a class variable.

From there, any class method (including arr()) can access that data.

```
class StringTokenizer {
    String str;
    StringTokenizer(String str) {this.str=str;}
    public String[] getTokens() {
        String[] tokens;
        tokens = this.str.split("\\s+");
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have changed "arr()" to "getTokens()"

Answer (score 0):

Method `arr()` has a parameter so when you call the method, you need to supply a `String`, for example:

```
String[] tokens = arr("This is a string that needs to be tokenized");
```